# PDO errorInfo 1062 duplicate entry key 1 doubts help pls kind of lost Updated debug error at the bottom

Tags: mysql, pdo

Hi guys i am trying to read some data from a php telnet cmd and parse it to update the specific results inside a mysql table.. the issue i am having is that its trhowing an error

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(5) "23000" 
    [1]=> int(1062) 
    [2]=> string(47) "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UC_cdata_ont_info'" 
}
```

fail to execute query

and below is the cmd i am running "if i just send the first 2 cmds.. show_pon0 and show_pon1 it reads from show_pon1 cmd.. data from 2 devices starting with 0/0xxxxxxxxx.. and it updates them correclty inside the table mysql..
But if i enable show_pon2 cmd togheter it reads 3 different devices data as the output below..

```
interface epon 0/0 

OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 1 all 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
      ID                    flag      state      state    state
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0/0  1  1   AC:4E:91:A6:CF:F5 active    online     success  match     Test1-.
 0/0  1  2   E0:67:B3:35:EF:76 active    powerdown  initial  initial   Test2.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total: 2, online 1

OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 2 all 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
      ID                    flag      state      state    state
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0/0  2  1   E0:E8:E6:4E:62:58 active    online     success  match     Test3.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total: 1, online 1

OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# 

OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)#
```

and the code below filters the following data

```
 0/0  1  1   AC:4E:91:A6:CF:F5 active    online     success  match     Test1.
 0/0  1  2   E0:67:B3:35:EF:76 active    powerdown  initial  initial   Test2.
 0/0  2  1   E0:E8:E6:4E:62:58 active    online     success  match     Test3.
```

And it stores it on the mysql table..

below the code

```
$show_pon[0] = "interface epon 0/0";  
$show_pon[1] = "show ont info 1 all";  
$show_pon[2] = "show ont info 2 all";  
//  $show_pon[2] = "show ont info 3 all";  
//  $show_pon[3] = "show ont info 4 all";  
//  $show_pon[4] = "show ont info 5 all";  
//  $show_pon[5] = "show ont info 6 all";  
//  $show_pon[6] = "show ont info 7 all";  
//  $show_pon[7] = "show ont info 8 all";  
//  $show_pon[8] = "show ont info 9 all";  
//  $show_pon[9] = "show ont info 10 all";  
//  $show_pon[10] = "show ont info 11 all";  
//  $show_pon[11] = "show ont info 12 all";  
//  $show_pon[12] = "show ont info 13 all";  
//  $show_pon[13] = "show ont info 14 all";  
//  $show_pon[14] = "show ont info 15 all";  
//  $show_pon[15] = "show ont info 16 all";   
     $debug = true;
        if ($debug) {
            $cache = '/tmp/cdata_ont_info.log';
            $contents = @file_get_contents($cache);
            if ($contents == false) 
            {
                $telnet->DoCommand($show_pon, $poninfo_resposta);// estatisticas resposta.. coloca no array o dump resposta 
                file_put_contents($cache, $poninfo_resposta);
            } else 
            {
                $poninfo_resposta = $contents;
            }
        } else 
        {
            $telnet->DoCommand($show_pon, $poninfo_resposta);// estatisticas resposta.. coloca no array o dump resposta
        }
         $filtro_resposta = $poninfo_resposta;
         preg_match_all('~^\h*(\d+/\d+)\h+(\d+)\h+(\d+)\h+([A-F\d]{2}(?::[A-F\d]{2}){5})\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)(?:\h+(\S+))?~m',$filtro_resposta,$m);
     $InputArray = array($m[0]);
     foreach ($InputArray as $str) 
     {
         
         $query_chunks = [];
         $query_data = [];  

         foreach( $str as $row )
         {              
          $query_chunks[] = "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,$id)";
          $query_data = array_merge($query_data, preg_split("/\s+/", trim($row)));  
         }
         $query = "INSERT INTO cdata_ont_info (frame_slot, pon, ont_id, mac_address, run_state, control_flag, match_state, config_state, description, olt_id) VALUES "  . implode( ', ', $query_chunks );
         $pdo_dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'mydbtestusr', 'mydbtestpasswd');
         $sth = $pdo_dbh->prepare( $query );
            if (!$sth) {
                        var_dump($sth->errorInfo());
                        die('ERRO!!! Falha na query!!!!');
                        }
                            
            if (!$sth->execute( $query_data )) 
                        {
                         var_dump($sth->errorInfo());
                         die('ERRO!!! Falha executando a query_data!!!!!!');
                        }
                        die(print_r($query_data, true)); 
      }
```

Like i said earlier.. if i just run the first 2 cmds.. show_pon1 and show_pon2.. it updates the data normally inside the mysql table.. but if i enable the 3rd cmd  show_pon2 or all the other cmds onwards.. it filters all the data from query_date like the example below but it will not update on the mysql table it will throw out the PDO error 1062 duplicate key1 code..

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 0/0 
    [1] => 1 
    [2] => 1 
    [3] => AC:4E:91:A6:CF:F5 
    [4] => active 
    [5] => online 
    [6] => success 
    [7] => match 
    [8] => VILERMINA-. 
    [9] => 0/0 
    [10] => 1 
    [11] => 2 
    [12] => E0:67:B3:35:EF:76 
    [13] => active 
    [14] => powerdown 
    [15] => initial 
    [16] => initial 
    [17] => Rosiley-Si. 
    [18] => 0/0 
    [19] => 2 
    [20] => 1 
    [21] => E0:E8:E6:4E:62:58 
    [22] => active 
    [23] => online 
    [24] => success 
    [25] => match 
    [26] => CLOVES-NAV. 
)
```

And attached below some pictures of the mysql db on the links below
[image]

[image]

UPDATE

below full output debug message error

```
> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UC_cdata_ont_info' in /var/www/html/isp/olt/olt_cdata.php on line 263
SQL: [213] INSERT INTO cdata_ont_info (frame_slot, pon, ont_id, mac_address, run_state, control_flag, match_state, config_state, description, olt_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,4), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,4), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,4) Sent SQL: [416] INSERT INTO cdata_ont_info (frame_slot, pon, ont_id, mac_address, run_state, control_flag, match_state, config_state, description, olt_id) VALUES ('0/0','1','1','AC:4E:91:A6:CF:F5','active','online','success','match','VILERMINA-.',4), ('0/0','1','2','E0:67:B3:35:EF:76','active','powerdown','initial','initial','Rosiley-Si.',4), ('0/0','2','1','E0:E8:E6:4E:62:58','active','online','success','match','CLOVES-NAV.',4) Params: 27 Key: Position #0: paramno=0 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #1: paramno=1 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #2: paramno=2 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #3: paramno=3 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #4: paramno=4 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #5: paramno=5 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #6: paramno=6 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #7: paramno=7 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #8: paramno=8 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #9: paramno=9 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #10: paramno=10 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #11: paramno=11 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #12: paramno=12 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #13: paramno=13 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #14: paramno=14 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #15: paramno=15 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #16: paramno=16 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #17: paramno=17 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #18: paramno=18 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #19: paramno=19 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #20: paramno=20 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #21: paramno=21 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #22: paramno=22 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #23: paramno=23 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #24: paramno=24 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #25: paramno=25 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #26: paramno=26 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 NULL ERRO!!! Falha executando a query_data!!!!!!
```

UPDATE2

below picture of the SHOW CREATE TABLE

[image]

Comment: Another incomplete error message. If you're going to post an error message as part of your question, post the **complete** message. There is more information there than just the error code.

Comment: Hi @TangentiallyPerpendicular
 well thats the output log that shows on the error only.. is there another PDO debuginfoerror that i could add?  Because when the query exectues on the PDO it does not stores the data on the mysql table.. and throws the exact same error i have posted at the top of the message.

Comment: Well after reading @TangentiallyPerpendicular comment, i have decided to study pdo a litle more and managed to get some aditional info on the logs, not sure if this will help but this is the output log now.   Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UC_cdata_ont_info' in /var/www/html/isp/olt/olt_cdata.php on line 265
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "23000" [1]=> int(1062) [2]=> string(47) "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UC_cdata_ont_info'" } ERROR!!! Failed executing query_data!!!!!!

Comment: So now you know which index is complaining about a duplicate key. From that you can see which column contains that data (you haven't posted the `CREATE TABLE` statement that would tell you that) and from that you can work out what data already exists. Then you can look at the source data you're inserting to determine why you're getting a duplicate.

Comment: hi @TangentiallyPerpendicular thanks, i will try to get the CREATE TABLE statement from the mysql..   i am kind of lost in a sense because the columns is empty i have deleted everything from the table left it blank.. if i just send the first cmd show_pon0 shown on top.. it processes the 2 devices data and stores it normaly inside the table, the querie gets updated on the mysql table normaly.. if i enable the show_pon1 cmd to add extra data from the other devices on the other cmd.. i can see it puts together the 3 devices data on the querie.. but throws out the error of duplicate.

Comment: hi @TangentiallyPerpendicular i have uploaded the show create table info on the first question picture added let me know if this the correct info you were asking?

Comment: looks like i kind of understood now.. basicaly my device has 8 ports.. each port as some devices plugged into it..  Port1 = PON1  device ONT id 1,2    Port2 =PON2  device ONT id1 .. i guess its this duplicate data that its blocking it from storing on the table.. so can i ignore the unique key? as each port.. start counting the devices from ont-id 1 up to 64 which is the maximum devices connected per port.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular first of all let me thank you for all the help u gave me.. it helped me understand where my problem was.. thanks alot mate.. i have found the unique key error i had on the ont_id columns and fixed it.. its now working as it should..

Answer (score 0):

issue solved, it was a problem with my columns on the mysql table, thanks to @TangentiallyPerpendicular help, i have managed to find the error on my mysql table which was defined as Unique key on ont_id column, soon as i have changed it.. the data was updated in the mysql table.